# Excluding hyphens after first instance

Tags: regex

I'm trying to develop a regex expression which pulls the first few characters before the first instance of a hyphen, and then saves the second group of elements after the first hyphen.

Here's the regex:

```
^([^-]*)(?(?=-)(\S.*)|())
```

And here are few test cases:

```
SSB x Dj Chad - Crazy Beat - Tarraxo
Dj [R]afaa [F]ox -Tarraxo Do Inicio Das Aulas ( Nova Escola Producões )
Dj Snakes Share - MaloncyBeatz - Perfecto
Tarraxo Das Brasileiras [2014] [TxiGa Pro]
```

The IF statement handles the last condition perfectly, but my issue is for the first few items, it returns the second group 'with' the hyphen instead of excluding it.

In other words:
`Dj Snakes Share - MaloncyBeatz - Perfecto` should return:

- Group 1: `Dj Snakes Share`
- Group 2: `MaloncyBeatz - Perfecto`

Instead, Group 2 is: `- MaloncyBeatz - Perfecto`

**Update**

https://regex101.com/r/2BQPNg/12

Using `^([^-]*)[^-]\W*(.*)`, it works, but it raises a problem for the last case (where there is no hyphen). It excludes the `]`.

Comment: Seems like it is working now on your test link.

Comment: @tima The last case now excludes the ']' at the end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

`^([^-]+?)\s*(?:-\s*(.*))?$`

```
^         // start of line
([^-]+?)  // 1+ not '-' chars, lazily matched (first captured group)
\s*       // 0+ white-space chars
(?:       // grouped, not captured
-         // dash
\s*(.*)   // 0+ white-space chars then anything (second captured group)
)?        // 0 or 1 time
$         // end of line
```

Flags: global, multi-line

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEEgEp/2)

501 steps reduced to 164 steps:

`^[^-]+$|^((?:\w[^-]*)?\w)\W+(\w.*)`

```
^                # start of line
[^-]+            # 1 or more not '-'
$                # end of line
|                # OR
^                # start of line
(                # start of group (captured)
(?:              # start of group (not captured)
\w[^-]*          # a word char then 0 or more not '-'
)?               # 0 or 1 times
\w)              # a word char, then end of group
\W+              # 1 or more non-word chars
(\w.*)           # a word char then 0 or more anything (captured)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FUfc0i/4)

Comment: This satisfies all conditions! Thank you!

Comment: This will be very slow as data grows. [At present](https://regex101.com/r/GEEgEp/3) It takes 595 steps as compared to [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/2BQPNg/15) that takes 76 steps.

Comment: @anubhava just [remove the lazy match](https://regex101.com/r/GEEgEp/4) and this answer is 16 steps in front of yours!

Comment: @UlysseBN: Those 16 steps are including an extra trailing space in group 1.

Comment: @anubhava Just use [`\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/GEEgEp/6) instead of `*` in that case, still 60. However this could break (and so could yours) if there is a bad formatting such as _name1- name2_. Or Wiktor variation, 66 steps for a neat result.

Comment: No, [now it doesn't even match the 5th match](https://regex101.com/r/GEEgEp/7) after taking 171 steps and here is [mine](https://regex101.com/r/2BQPNg/16) taking 85 steps to find all 5 matches.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, yours fails on `a-b`, `a- b`, `aa-bb`, etc. I added a new one with less steps than prior in my answer.

Comment: As per all the OP's examples hyphens have at least a space before.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this regex:

```
^([^-]*)[^-]\W*(.*)
```

Here, you have an extra `[^-]` in your regex that is causing first group to match one character less than the match.

You can use this regex:

```
^([^-]*)(?:\s+-\s*(.*))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2BQPNg/15)

Comment: I see, basically instead of [^-], it's best to simply use the \W* to capture all the non letter characters. So far, I haven't had any problems, but how would your regex address this case: `Dj Snakes Share - [MaloncyBeatz] - Perfecto`